# Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, polyfills, zone.js

**Error I get**

```
            Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
      Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
          at Function.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.assertZonePatched (zone.js:58)
          at new NgZone (core.js:24212)
          at getNgZone (core.js:24925)
          at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (core.js:24823)
          at core.js:24867
          at exceljs.min.js:3
          at MutationObserver.n (exceljs.min.js:3)
          at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
          at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:161)
          at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (zone.js:144)
```

I am posting a small part of zone.js from where i am getting this error

```
     function Zone(parent, zoneSpec) {
            this._parent = parent;
            this._name = zoneSpec ? zoneSpec.name || 'unnamed' : '<root>';
            this._properties = zoneSpec && zoneSpec.properties || {};
            this._zoneDelegate =
                new ZoneDelegate(this, this._parent && this._parent._zoneDelegate, zoneSpec);
        }
        Zone.assertZonePatched = function () {
            if (global['Promise'] !== patches['ZoneAwarePromise']) {
                throw new Error('Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` ' +
                    'has been overwritten.\n' +
                    'Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded ' +
                    'after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. ' +
                    'If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)');
            }
        };
```

The above error is thrown. I am literally struggling hard to solve this.

**When I get this error**

I had a task in my project to export excel sheet with styling. I found a package called [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs). After including this i started getting this error.

**Some related documents from exceljs.js readme file**

```
## ES5 Imports
```

To use the ES5 transpiled code, use the dist/es5 path.

```js
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs/dist/es5');
```

**Note:** The ES5 build has an implicit dependency on a number of polyfills which are no longer
 explicitly added by exceljs.
 You will need to add "core-js" and "regenerator-runtime" to your dependencies and
 include the following requires in your code before the exceljs import:

```js
// polyfills required by exceljs
require('core-js/modules/es.promise');
require('core-js/modules/es.object.assign');
require('core-js/modules/es.object.keys');
require('regenerator-runtime/runtime');

// ...

const ExcelJS = require('exceljs/dist/es5');
```

Browserify

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-polyfill/6.26.0/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="exceljs.js"></script>
```

I am using es6. So what i am missing .please help me out.

**Angular version details.**

```
            Angular CLI: 7.3.9
        Node: 10.0.0
        OS: linux x64
        Angular: 8.0.0
        ... core

        Package                             Version
        -------------------------------------------------------------
        @angular-devkit/architect           0.13.9
        @angular-devkit/build-angular       0.13.9
        @angular-devkit/build-optimizer     0.13.9
        @angular-devkit/build-webpack       0.13.9
        @angular-devkit/core                7.3.9
        @angular-devkit/schematics          7.3.9
        @angular/animations                 7.2.15
        @angular/cdk                        8.1.4
        @angular/cli                        7.3.9
        @angular/common                     7.2.15
        @angular/compiler                   7.2.15
        @angular/compiler-cli               7.2.15
        @angular/forms                      7.2.15
        @angular/http                       7.2.15
        @angular/language-service           7.2.15
        @angular/material                   8.1.4
        @angular/platform-browser           7.2.15
        @angular/platform-browser-dynamic   7.2.15
        @angular/router                     7.2.15
        @ngtools/webpack                    7.3.9
        @schematics/angular                 7.3.9
        @schematics/update                  0.13.9
        rxjs                                6.3.3
        typescript                          3.2.4
        webpack
```

Answer (score -1):

By the time of your question you have probably figured this out by now... comment out this line from your polyfills.ts

```
// import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
```